# How to use array.map inside a wrapping function and return the mapped array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I may have an obvious problem, but I'm having trouble solving it. I want to map an array of stories `mappedArray` within a function `ShowStoryListView` and return the `mappedArray`. The function takes `props` as input that contain the `stories`.

However when i try to exectue the function i get the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: story.map is not a function
```

```
function ShoWStoryListView (props) {
      const story = props

      const mappedArray = story.map((story, index) => (
            <MDBRow id={index} key={story.id} style={{ margin: '10px', display: 'inline-block' }}>
              <MDBCol>
                <MDBCard style={{ width: '22rem' }}>
                  <MDBCardImage className="img-fluid" src={pic} waves />
                  <MDBCardBody>
                    <MDBCardTitle>Title: {story.title}</MDBCardTitle>
                    <MDBCardTitle>Place: {story.place}</MDBCardTitle>
                    <MDBCardTitle>Author: {story.author.username}</MDBCardTitle>
                    <MDBCardText>{story.content}</MDBCardText>
                    <audio controls src={story.audio.url}>
                      Your browser does not support the
                      <code>audio</code> element.
                    </audio>
                    {story.story_owner_permission === true ? <MDBBtn href="#">Click me</MDBBtn> : null}
                    <Link
                      to={`/story/${story.id}`}
                      className="badge badge-warning"
                      style={{ marginLeft: '100px' }}
                    >
                      Details
                    </Link>
                  </MDBCardBody>
                </MDBCard>
              </MDBCol>
            </MDBRow>
          )
          )

     return (

      {mappedArray}

     ) 
    }
```

When i use the `mappedArray` outside the `ShoWStoryListView` it works somehow. I wonder why it is not working inside the function?

Im happy for any clarifications.

Comment: If `story.map` is not a function then `story` isn't an array. Log it to find out what it is.

Answer (score 0):

Use `function ShoWStoryListView ({ story }) {`  or  `const { story } = props` ?